# Issue on creating token on oauth2

Tags: c#

I have this code in C#, however, I'm having an issue on the line

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
```

I get this error

> StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:

When I try it in Postman, it successfully creates the token, but not in C#.

```
string url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "scope", "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" },
            { "client_id",  client_id },
            { "client_secret", client_secret }
        };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));

return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AccessTokenModel>();
```

Comment: Do you replace the `{tenant_id}` value in your URL with the correct value?

Comment: Yes. replaced with the correct Id

Answer (score -1):

Updating .Netframework from 4.5 to 4.6 resolve the issue.